# How can I interchange the function of headphone and microphone jack with software?

Tags: laptop, audio

I have a Toshiba satellite C850-f04y PC and the headphone jack is not functioning but the microphone works fine. Currently I am unable to replace the hardware (non-functioning jack) so I want to interchange the function of the microphone and headphone jack (since I don't want to use the microphone).

Can somebody tell me if this is possible to do with some software, and if some detail about how can I get and use that software?

Comment: Not sure. Couldn't you use USB headphones?

Comment: Where did you read this was even possible.  Because it sounds like a horrible idea

Answer (score 2):

This is very much dependant on the audio card and will vary from model to model.

As a general rule - I would advise but this is probably not possible as the curcit board on the sound card will be built to serve a purpose and that jack will be "wired" to components which are geared towards input rather than output.

I think your safest bet would be to go and purchase a new card or USB headphones.

You could possibly do this by stripping down, rewriting and re-loading a new set of drivers which treat the input as an output - but based on how long this would take, its cheaper in terms of time to replace the whole laptop, let alone the audio card.